# How do I create a line break in display-mode equation material?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

How do I make a new line in $\LaTeX$?

---

```
$$2^2+2=6
3^2+3=12$$
```

returns

$$2^2+2=6
3^2+3=12$$

which is wrong.

Comment: Welcome! Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
2^2+2&=4\\
3^2+3&=12
\end{align}
\end{document}`

Comment: or `$$2^2+2=4$$  $$3^2+3=12$$`.

Comment: Never use `$$... $$` in latex, it is tex code and does not follow latex configurations

Comment: @C.F.G -- Although what you suggest does produce two lines, if they occur at the end of a page, the page can be broken between them.  Also, there is too much space between the two lines.  These are situations over which you have no automatic control.

Comment: I have removed a few comments here. As others noted, the entire StackOverflow model is based on the idea of collaborative editing. The edits made were all aimed at clarifying the question, and thus within the 'improvement' scope which is deliberately encouraged. In terms of comments: if any are problematic, simply flag them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While LaTeX and MathJax use similar syntax, their underlying engines are very different. Whereas it's possible to force a line break using the approach shown in your posting, that approach is not syntactically valid in a LaTeX document.

If all you need to achieve is show two displayed equations, one below the other, in a LaTeX document, I suggest you (a) load the `amsmath` package in the preamble and (b) use its `gather` environment in the body of the document:

```
\begin{gather}
2^2+2=6\\
3^2+3=12
\end{gather}
```

Observe (a) the use of `\\` to force a linebreak and (b) the absence of all-blank lines inside the `gather` environment.